# Unit Test in Angular for async logout function

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I am new in angular and tried to create unit test for it. In my **component.ts**, I have the code like this

```
  async doLogout() {
    const idUser = parseInt(this.authService.getUserData.id, 10);
    this.authService.setRedirectUrl('');
    this.router.navigate(['auth/login'], { state: { isLogout: true } });
  }
```

Nah in here, I little bit confuse about how to write it in **component.spec.ts**. I try write like this:

```
let routerSpy = {navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')};

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        ApolloTestingModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseconf),
        AngularFireMessagingModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MessagingService, useClass: MessagingServiceMock },
        { provide:ThemeService, useClass: ThemeServiceMock },
        { provide: NotificationService, useClass: NotificationServiceMock },
        { provide: GetAvailableGroupListUsecase, useClass: GetAvailableGroupListUsecaseMock }, 
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents()
  }));

it('async doLogOut', fakeAsync(() => {
component.doLogOut()
expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/auth/login']);
}))
```

What did I miss guys? your help means a lot for me

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: yes, the error message is : Error: Expected spy navigate to have been called with:
  [ [ '/auth/login' ] ]
but it was never called. @ammadkh

Comment: The code provided does not show how you create the `component`. Please update the question with all relevant code parts.

Comment: updated @PhilippMeissner

Comment: Still missing the code where you assign `component` something :D

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing `async` about the method, I would remove it and see if it works without `async` so you don't have to wait for any promises.

Try this:

```
 doLogout() {
    const idUser = parseInt(this.authService.getUserData.id, 10);
    this.authService.setRedirectUrl('');
    this.router.navigate(['auth/login'], { state: { isLogout: true } });
  }
.....
it('async doLogOut', () => {
  component.doLogOut()
  expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/auth/login']);
});
```